# Como operan los operadores de bits en un caso particular

Tags: python, funciones

Encontré este código en internet, especificamente hecho para conseguir un [Número vampiro](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_vampiro), solo es un fragmento, me dijeron de otros métodos usando permutaciones pero no sabía que tan fiable era porque algo me decía que se podrían repetir número en el proceso de cálculo, así que me puse a buscar y conseguí un código general y lo modifiqué para python, este es un fragmento solamente.

```
    def factorPairs(n):
        li = self.divisors(n)
        del li[0]; del li[-1]
        pairs=[]
        for x in range(-((-len(li))>>1)):
            pairs.append([li[x], li[-x-1]])
        return pairs
```

Quiero saber como funciona `for x in range(-((-len(li))>>1)):`, simplemente no entiendo que hace esa línea de código, ya averigüé sobre operadores de bits y nada.
Si alguien me puede ayudar con unha explicación, lo agradecería.

Si se requiere el código completo para entender mejor, me dicen y edito la publicación.

Comment: Es una forma super retorcida de poner `range(len(li)//2)`. Desplazar 1 bit a la derecha equivale a dividir por 2 si la longitud es par (y es más rápido que la división, pero la pérdida de legibilidad no compensa la mínima ganancia en velocidad en  una instrucción que de todas formas se ejecutará una sola vez). Y lo de el doble signo menos es otro truco horriblemente ilegible para el caso en que la longitud sea impar.

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta el caso impar podrías poner `range(sum(divmod(len(li),2)))` que es también bastante ilegible (¿pero menos?) o bien `range(len(li)//2+len(li)%2)` que es lo mismo pero más explícito (y con el inconveniente de ejecutar len dos veces)

Comment: @abulafia con divmod, yo lo entiendo, numerador y denominador, entonces lo que pusieron allí es equivalente a un `for x in range(len(li)//2+len(li)%2)`? la diferencia que usando esos operadores tiene una ejecución "más eficiente"?

Comment: Apostaría que el original está escrito en C++.